# Summation, capital pi properties

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I know that for summation,

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{x} a_{i} + \sum_{i = x+1}^{n} a_{i} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i}$$

Does the same concept apply for capital pi? Such as:

$$\prod_{i = 1}^{x} a_{i} \cdot\prod_{i = x+1}^{n} a_{i} = \prod_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i}$$

I am trying to show that

$$\prod_{i = 1}^{0} a_{i} = 1$$

Comment: It does apply. But the question is, how can the index go from $i=1$ to $0$? The convention is that the summation index should be increasing with step $1$. (Or, are you asking why the empty product is one?)

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг yes why the empty product is one

Comment: The empty product is one by convention. The product is a binary operation, so it requires two operands, hence at least one number is required for evaluation. If there is no operand, then one cannot prove mathematically that the empty product is one, because if there is nothing to multiply, then one does not have a reason to prefer any number over the other, so the convention equating it to one is adopted to make computations and proofs of certain theorems easier. Here's where you can get better information : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product

Comment: It is often convenient to define the product of the members of the empty set to be 1, and the sum of the members of the empty set to be 0. ...

Answer (score 2):

The notation $\displaystyle\prod_{i=n}^m a_i$ can also be written as $\displaystyle\prod_{i\in\{n,..,m\}}a_i$.

This notation can be generalised as $\displaystyle \prod_{i\in A}a_i$ for any set of indices, $A\subseteq\Bbb N^+$.

We do want the following to hold for any *disjoint* sets of indices, $A, B$.

$$\prod_{i\in A\cup B} a_i = (\prod_{i\in A} a_i)\cdot(\prod_{i\in B} a_i)$$

Since the empty set is disjoint with any set, then this means we must have: $$\prod_{i\in A\cup\emptyset} a_i = (\prod_{i\in A} a_i)\cdot(\prod_{i\in \emptyset} a_i)$$

Because $A\cup\emptyset = A$, then clearly the empty product needs to equal $1$. $$\prod_{i\in\{\}} a_i = 1$$

---

PS: by the same reasoning, the empty series equals $0$. $$\sum_{i\in\{\}} a_i = 0$$